# escoffier : Mackerel Anglaise

Tags: fish, french-cuisine, poaching

One of the poached fish recipe's in Ma Cuisine is Mackerel Anglaise, it's one of those two sentence recipes. My english translation is:

> English Mackerel:
> Cut the mackerel in sections and poach in court boullion
> with some fennel tops added. Serve with pureed green
> gooseberries.

A few questions:

- has anyone tried this recipe, or something similar?
- what is a good substitute for gooseberries?
- my initial impression was that the gooseberries are pureed raw and mixed with the poaching liquid. Is that correct?

thanks

Comment: Kiwi is the new name for Chinese gooseberries, so maybe they’d work as a substitute?

Answer (score 4):

In *The Escoffier Cookbook* (the English translation of *Le Guide Culinaire*), the corresponding recipe ("Boiled mackerel with gooseberry sauce") says to serve the sauce "with" the mackerel and describes it as follows:

> Cook one lb. of green gooseberries in a copper preserving kettle with three oz. of sugar and enough water to cover them, and then rub them through a fine sieve.

*Ma Cuisine* was written some decades later so it's possible his thinking had changed since then, but if so you'd expect him to call it out a bit more.

As for substitutes, the sauce sounds broadly similar to a tart, strained cranberry sauce, which would have a *very* different color and would lack the floral notes but otherwise be a decent approximation. In a comment on moscafj's answer, jmk mentions rhubarb as well; that would be a better approximation for taste and color, but the texture would be quite different.

(Incidentally, a saucepan would be a good modern substitute for a "copper preserving kettle").

Answer (score 1):

I would ***not*** think the gooseberries are pureed and added to the poaching liquid.  "Serve with pureed gooseberries" implies that the fish is cooked, then served with the gooseberries as an accompaniment. Not sure where you are located, but canned gooseberries are sold (at least in the US) on Amazon.com. They can also be occasionally found fresh in various regions of the US (not sure about outside the US, but if you specify your location, perhaps someone can help).  If you don't have access, a reasonable substitute is green grapes.

Comment: Bear in mind that canned gooseberries are usually sweeter as they are in a sugar syrup. To me fresh gooseberries are closer to the flavour profile of rhubarb than grapes but that may depend on the cultivar

Comment: Maybe some type of combo would work as a substitute, a sweet-sour-vaguely floral fruit combo as an accompaniment. Mackerel is an oily fish, so something acidic would help balance it out.